# How to restart CALayer animation while it is in progress?

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I used this scenario with UIView's animations with no problems, but can't get it working with CALayer animation.

I have made a playground to demonstrate the problem:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class EventHandler {
    @objc func onClick(_ button: UIButton) {

        button.layer.removeAllAnimations()

        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        print("RED")

        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
            button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            print("BLACK")
        })

        let colorAnimation = CABasicAnimation()
        colorAnimation.toValue = UIColor.black.cgColor
        colorAnimation.duration = 5
        button.layer.add(colorAnimation, forKey: "borderColor")
        CATransaction.commit()

    }
}

let eventHandler = EventHandler()

let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))

button.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
button.layer.borderWidth = 20
button.addTarget(eventHandler, action: #selector(EventHandler.onClick(_:)), for: .touchDown)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = button
```

What I want is when I click the button in the middle of animation, the animation should start over. But it seems like when I call removeAllAnimations() the completion block of the original animation is executed not before I set color to RED but after it.

Comment: Have I understood correctly that the button is meant to animate its border color from red to black, that it's black when not animating, and that when restarting the animation is restarts jumps to red again?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted. I have just found the solution by setting fromValue to the animation object.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem by setting fromValue to the animation object. Here is working version:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class EventHandler {
    @objc func onClick(_ button: UIButton) {

        button.layer.removeAllAnimations()

        let colorAnimation = CABasicAnimation()
        colorAnimation.fromValue = UIColor.red.cgColor
        colorAnimation.toValue = UIColor.black.cgColor
        colorAnimation.duration = 5
        button.layer.add(colorAnimation, forKey: "borderColor")   
    }
}

let eventHandler = EventHandler()

let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))

button.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
button.layer.borderWidth = 20
button.addTarget(eventHandler, action: #selector(EventHandler.onClick(_:)), for: .touchDown)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = button
```

Comment: In that case you don't need the completion block (the property value is always a black color).